# Best way to call a method - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop, methods

I have these two classes, but I want to know what is the best way to call a function inside a class.

I like to use this one with attributes:

```
class myclass():
    def myfunction(self):
        return self.x + self.y

z = myclass()
z.x = 4
z.y = 3
print z.myfunction()
```

But I don't know if it's correct. Or should I be using this instead the last one?

```
class myclass():
    def myfunction(self,x,y):
        return x + y

z = myclass()
print z.myfunction(4,3)
```

Comment: The second one is the usual way of doing it. I wouldn't even have thought of the first one. Perhaps there's some missing context since you simplified the problem?

Comment: Are you going to use x and y somewhere else in your class?

Comment: Yes. And this is just an example, lets say i have a lot of methods in my class. And method "a" calls method "b" and method "b" needs some values from method "a". That's what i want to know. But then, i'm a bit confused because i don't know if calling a method using attributes instead parameters is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends. Are `x` and `y` part of the state of `myclass()` or are they something external interacting with the class?

If `x` and `y` are not part of the state of the `myclass()` instance, they should not be stored in attributes. They would be passed in as arguments instead.

Lets say you have a *car* object, and you need to know what would happen to the car if it collided with something else. That 'something else' isn't part of the car, so you'd call the `car.collide()` method and pass in the 'something else' in as an argument:

```
car.collide(something_else)
```

but the car speed at the time of collision, as well as things like the mass of the car, are  part of the *state* of the car object, so they are attributes:

```
car.speed = 80
car.mass = 1200
car.collide(something_else)
```

Comment: Much better than my answer. Thanks for contextualizing the abstract!

Comment: Lets say i have a lot of methods in my class. And method "a" calls method "b" and method "b" needs some values from method "a". That's what i want to know. But then, i'm a bit confused because i don't know if calling a method using attributes instead parameters is correct.

Comment: @Vashh: if you are setting attributes *just* to call the method, then that's not correct. Attributes say something about the object and usually dictate behaviour across more than one method.

Comment: @Vashh if you have method `a` calling method `b` calling method `a`, you have a problem! If method `b` needs a parameter that can be supplied to it by method `a`, that's fine.

Comment: lol, that's what i tried to say, method b needs a parameter that is supplied to it by method a.

Comment: But thans, i think i got it, but still, i'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Vashh: Do both methods need to know the speed of the car? Then that's part of the car state and not an argument to pass from one method to the next. Or are you trying to tell the car how hard to hit the breaks? Then pass in the pressure on the pedal to the other method as an argument.

Comment: Yeah, both methods need to know the speed of the car. I guess i need to read more about it to understand a bit better, so i won't make something bad. My code works perfect, but that it works doesn't mean that it's correct. Thanks, Martijn

Comment: @Vashh: I'd not worry too much about this; with time and repetition comes experience, you'll start to recognise when values are part of the state and when they are not.